# Is the content on disk in cloud (Azure, AWS) zeroized prior to re-releasing to other users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2

Wanted to know if cloud based platforms such as Azure and Amazon zeroize the content on the hard disk whenever an 'instance' is 'deleted' and prior to making it available for other users?

I've tried using ['dd' command](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/operating-systems/question/use-dd-to-read-data-from-a-raw-disk-device-101809/) on an Amazon-LightSail instance and it appears that the raw data is indeed zeroized. However was not sure if it was by chance (i just tried few random lengths) or if they actually take care to do that.

The concern is, if I leave passwords in configuration files, then someone who comes along would be able to read them (theoretically). Same goes for data in a database.

Comment: This seems like a question that should go directly to AWS/Azure, as unless they specifically address this in documentation, any answer here would be speculation.

Comment: Azure atleast says that their support team is active on stackoverflow. So just wanted to give it a try. Although it would still be difficult to say if anyone is a legitimate Microsoft MVP or not (and its amazon equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Generically, the solution to your concern typically used by Azure is storage encryption.

Your data is encrypted by default at the platform level with a key specific to your subscription; when the data or resource is removed, whether or not the storage is zeroed, it is effective inaccessible to a resource deployed on the same storage in another subscription.

Comment: This makes sense. Was able to look up few links too. Will post as answer separately. However those links still don't quite answer the question clearly.